# Pass query value into subquery in where condition

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables A and B keeping employee details of two different zones. There is a possibility that some employees worked in both zone and can be in both table. Only column that will tell is the 'date_from' which indicate the employee started working on that zone on that date.
I need to pull employee names from Both A and B. 
That can be achieve by

```
select *(
select name from A union 
Select name from B)
```

The problem is if the employee in A worked in B with in a day period of 200 days that should not show. Same vise versa. How can i achieve this.

Comment: is there also a date_to column? When no, how can the day period be calculated?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .  We need to see table schema, sample data, and expected results.

Comment: Hi Schurik, Yes there is date_to column..